# How to stop Camel Context immediately?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-scheduled

I have a camel application where I create below structure

```
main thread 
        create Camel Context
          addRoute(routeBuilder1)
          addRoute(routeBuilder2)
        context.start
```

RouteBuilder1

```
    R11 
    R12
    R13
    R14
```

RouteBuilder2

```
    R21
    R22
```

In very specific situation, I need to stop the context(stop all processing right now). When I use context.shutdown,I noticed that if a route processing is in progress, camel is not able to stop it(called as gracefull shutdown), and that route continue processing. Whereas,in my case I need to hard stop everything immediately.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `timeout` field of [DefaultShutdownStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultShutdownStrategy.html).

Example:

```
context.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(0);
context.getShutdownStrategy().setShutdownNowOnTimeout(true);
```

UPDATE:

I'm not sure, but maybe it should work with 1 millisec timeout (you can set the TimeUnit on the shutdownStrategy)

```
context.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
context.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(1);
context.getShutdownStrategy().setShutdownNowOnTimeout(true)
```

Comment: **setTimeout(0);**   will not work, camel needs positive timeout value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this related question?

[How to properly stop camelContext from being killed in a standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089949/how-to-properly-stop-camelcontext-from-being-killed-in-a-standalone-application)

Maybe you can try it in the same way using "kill -9".